# Oracle Select query to find combination on same column

Tags: sql, oracle

Need some help to search for certain combination from the same column.

Table value:

```
COLUMN1  COLUMN2 COLUMN3
WF1      Email   AA
WF1      Letter  BB
WF2      Email   AA
WF2      Letter  BB
WF2      Pen     CC
```

If (Column 1 = WF1) + (Column2 = Email and Letter) + (Column2 = Letter and Column3 = BB), print 'N':

```
 COLUMN1         COLUMN2     COLUMN3
    **WF1**      **Email**   AA
    **WF1**      **Letter**  **BB**
    WF2          Email       AA
    WF2          Letter      BB
    WF2          Pen         CC
```

I tried the following query but got stuck:

```
select 
  case 
    when max(result) = 2 
      then 
        case when instrument in ('Email', 'Letter') and gem_contract_type = 'BB'
         then 'N'
        else 'Y'
        end
  else
    'Y'
  end 
   from(
select column2, column3, 
count(*) over (partition by column1 order by column2) result
  from 
(select * from table1 where column = 'WF1')
  );
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? `(Column2 = Email and Letter)`, for example, is confusing - it can't be both, unless you're looking at all rows (perhaps grouped by `Column1`) in your example. And none of the rows have `Column1 = WF`.

Comment: @EdGibbs: I am trying to create a select query that will search for 'WF1' in column1. Then 'WF1' has 'Letter' and 'Email' in column2, together with value 'BB' --> i should print 'N', else all other combination should print 'Y'

Comment: @SOaddict: Sorry, didnt paste my query earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this isn't the full answer I hope it's at least a step in the right direction...

First, this will return a list of all `Column1` values which have both `Email` *and* `Letter` in `Column2`:

```
SELECT Column1
FROM myTable
WHERE Column2 IN ('Email', 'Letter')
GROUP BY Column1
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Column2) = 2
```

You can left join this to your table to get the results I think you want:

```
WITH EmAndLet AS (
  SELECT Column1
  FROM myTable
  WHERE Column2 IN ('Email', 'Letter')
  GROUP BY Column1
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Column2) = 2
)
SELECT
  MyTable.Column1,
  MyTable.Column2,
  MyTable.Column3,
  CASE WHEN EmAndLet.Column1 IS NOT NULL AND MyTable.Column3 = 'BB'
    THEN 'N'
    ELSE 'Y'
    END
FROM myTable
LEFT JOIN EmAndLet ON myTable.Column1 = EmAndLet.Column1
```

When left joining, if there isn't a corresponding `EmAndLet` row then `EmAndLet.Column1` will be null. If there is a corresponding row, `EmAndLet.Column1` will have a value and will pass the `IS NOT NULL` test in the `CASE` statement above. Hope this makes sense :)